How do I stop the cloth from moving too much upward and deforming so much that it tears apart?
I been messing with cloth simulations for a few months now and I just can't get it to do much of what I actually want it to do. I tried experimenting with the stiffness while keeping the damping low then messing with gravity, but things got worse as time went on. For this I'm just trying to make the cloth move but not at a fast pace while still staying low not going upward than ripping apart or deforming. I also wonder if its because of the long simulation that's making it do that.
What am I doing wrong here? I'm unsure what can be done to make the desired effect of character walking and the trench coat just falling along.
Blender file here
https://workupload.com/file/kFyrVquynTa

cloth simulation relies heavily on good topology. Yours...

isn't suitable. You should try to make quads with somehow equal width and height so that Blender can calculate the simulation easily. Also it shouldn't be too high poly.
If that still doesn't work, you can try to scale up everything by 10 or 50 which helps in most cases.

I see. It makes sense now this is really essential, yet somehow, I never even thought about this. Curious question though how do I make all quads same with widths and height?

i would recommend watching some cloth tutorials like this https://youtu.be/W9GDWKzf1mc?si=F18gO7BBgmha4LOK and rebuild them first, if successful, you can build your own. Don't believe that you know how to do it by just watching.....it is a huge difference between watching and doing it yourself.

Thank you. I knew eventually I'd have to learn sewing so now is a good time as ever. Restarting on the trench coat would be better than skipping out on learning something new that will help me far more in the long run.

you are welcome and....right!
